# Listing checkboxes from two tables and comparing selected data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, checkbox, asp-classic

I need some help solving this problem. I have a system for applying different filter values to products (red, blue, wood , metal).

I have two tables that look like this. (productID) is gathered from a table called "product". To get the productID I will use a request.querystring

### **tbl_filter**

**filterID   |   FilterName**

### **tbl_filter_join**

**fjoinID    |    filterID  |   ProductID**

My idea here is that I will list all filters (tbl_filters) dynamically as checkboxes and then compare if they have been added to the (tbl_filter_join), if so the checkbox is checked.

I'm not sure if can be solved in a SQL query or if I need some programming as well. My programming language is classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

declate a variable filtervariable and put all filters saperated by comma and value with single quote such as 'red','green'

and build a sql string in code

```
sql = "select * from
tbl_filter f inner join tbl_filter_join j on f.filterID =j.filterID 
where FilterName in ("+ filtervariable+" )"
```